# Sending mail through outlook using php script shows blank screen

Tags: php

We are trying to send an outlook mail using php code snippet as shown below.
   But when we run the code using localhost, it just shows a blank screen. No      mail is being sent or received. 
    Can someone help us here? Thanks in advance.

**Outlook.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> MY MAIL </title>
</head>
<?php
$account="abc@outlook.com";
$password="****";
$to="xyz@outlook.com";
$from="abc@outlook.com";
$from_name="ABC";
$msg="Hello";
$subject="Hello World";

include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username= $account;
$mail->Password= $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $from_name;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
if(!$mail->send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-Mail has been sent";
}
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is an "outlook mail"? I do know "email messages".

Comment: Start looking into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ or ask here. You _cannot_ program in php without monitoring that log file!

Answer (score 0):

Try this php mail code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> MY MAIL </title>
</head>
<?php
$account="abc@outlook.com";
$password="****";
$to="xyz@outlook.com";
$from="abc@outlook.com";
$from_name="ABC";
$msg="Hello";
$subject="Hello World";

include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
 $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a object to that class.
$mail->IsMail();
//$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->Subject =  $subject;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $first_name." ".$surname;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
//$mail->AddBCC('seo@infiniteitsolutions.com.au');
$mail->Body = $mailBody;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-Mail has been sent";
}
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your mailer by setting a parameter.

```
// enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;  // 1 = errors and messages
OR
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // 2 = messages only

//Send email
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

You can check complete example here

[PHPMailer debug example code](http://anasthecoder.blogspot.ae/2016/10/php-mailer-debug-example.html)